# Extract DATE only from DATE/TIME

Tags: excel

Imported data is in *2020-08-31 20:42:01 UTC* needs to be *20-08-31* to allow to use *DAYS* formula

Comment: `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))` if the date is in `A1`.

Comment: =INT(A2) works with time noted as AM or PM, but the UTC is not letting me format result as a date

Comment: `=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," UTC",""))`.

Comment: First option works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`=DATE(YEAR(A1), MONTH(A1), DAY(A1))`

- This is probably the more correct way of doing things as the method below can occasionally give odd results around the OLEDATE epoch

---

`=INT(A1)`

- This is the quick and dirty way that works becasue excel stores datetimes as doubles, the integer part is the date and the decimal is the time (e.g. 6AM = 0.25, 6PM = 0.75)

Comment: Nope, you gotta get rid of the `UTC` first.

Comment: Yep. Didn't read the question properly! :-( I'd go with your comment as the answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

With your text date in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))
```

and format as:

[image]

This yields a genuine date that can be used in the `=DAYS()` function.